# Creating XSL for multiple XML with different element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have been looking to create an XSL for multiple XML.Below is the sample XML which is one of the many XML's. The difference is that in `<ItemRequest>` in place of `<m.Currency>` there are other elements.  I need to display only `ItemRequest` which should be compatible to all the XML's.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stylesheet.xsl" ?>
<ServiceRequest xmlns:m="urn:messages.service.com"
    xmlns="urn:control.services.com" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <RequestHeader>
        <Service>Blah</Service>
        <Operation>Blah1</Operation>
    </RequestHeader>
    <m:ItemRequest>
        <ServiceRequest xmlns="urn:control.com" xmlns:m="urn:messages.service.com" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <RequestHeader>
                <Service>Blah</Service>
                <Operation>Blah2</Operation>
            </RequestHeader>
            <m:Currency>
                <m:MaintType>a</m:MaintType>
                <m:BackOffice>b</m:BackOffice>
                <m:Code>c</m:Code>
                <m:Number>%00</m:Number>
                <m:EditCode>1</m:EditCode>
            </m:Currency>
        </ServiceRequest>
    </m:ItemRequest>
</ServiceRequest>
```

Output: Something similar to

```
<h1>Operation: Currency</h1>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>MainType</td>
        <td>BackOffice</td>
        <td>Code</td>
        <td>Number</td>
        <td>EditCode</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>%00</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your xml is not well formed. Your prolog should be `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and your stylesheet process instruction is incomplete.

Comment: I am sorry. I am new to stackoverflow. I did formatted the xml code.And as you mentioned prolog is same as above.

Comment: Are you sure you can have a `ServiceRequest` inside a `m:ItemRequest`? Do you have a XSD which describes the different XMLs that you may have as input?

Comment: You also have two different default namespaces: `urn:control.services.com` for the elements in the external `ServiceRequest` and `urn:control.com` for the unprefixed elements in the internal `ServiceRequest`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have two default namespaces in different parts of your XML source, I mapped each one to a different prefix: `ns1` for the outer namespace, `ns2` for the inner namespace. I used XPath expressions that ignore part of the node hierarchy. This will work for the input XML you posted (extracting data from `m:Currency`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:ns1="urn:control.services.com" 
    xmlns:ns2="urn:control.com"
    xmlns:m="urn:messages.service.com" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1><xsl:value-of select="ns1:ServiceRequest/m:ItemRequest//ns2:Operation"/></h1>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ns1:ServiceRequest/m:ItemRequest//m:Currency"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="m:Currency">
        <table>
            <tr><xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="headers"/></tr>
            <tr><xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="data"/></tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="m:Currency/*" mode="headers">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(name(.), ':')"/></td>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="m:Currency/*" mode="data">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You said `m:Currency` is just an example, and you have other elements. This XSL will work only with that example. If you add to your question a XML Schema describing the other inputs you accept, it may be possible to write a stylesheet for other scenarios.

Comment: There are like 20 xml the structure is always same but instead of currency there is addresstype, country, entitytype etc. Could you suggest if some kind of variable can be used in place of that element??

Comment: I tried to run all my XML by changing "m:*" and it worked...Thank you so much